# How to combine 2 SQL queries into one without using union

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 queries that want to be combined into one query, I can't use union all because they have different types of rows that need to be printed out.

```
require 'connect.php';

    //$query="SELECT SUM(sales.price) as pricee, sales.date as dates FROM sales GROUP BY sales.date UNION ALL SELECT SUM(purchase.price) as pricey, purchase.date FROM purchase GROUP BY purchase.date ";
    $query = "SELECT sales.date AS dates, purchase.date, SUM(sales.price) AS pricey, SUM(purchase.price) AS price FROM sales,purchase GROUP BY sales.date, purchase.date";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $date[]=$row['date'];
            $price[]=$row['price'];
            $pricey[]=$row['pricey'];
            $dates[]=$row['dates'];

        }
        $res= [
            'price'=>$price,
            'data'=>$date,
        ];
        echo json_encode($res);
    }
    else{
        echo"ERROR";
    }
```

When I sum it up using sales database it works, but when I add up the purchase database the sum values are not irrelevant to the database. Thanks in advance
Showing the right sum values:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(price) AS price, date FROM sales GROUP BY date";
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FShm3.png)
Showing the false sum price values:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(sales.price) AS price, sales.date FROM sales,purchase GROUP BY sales.date";
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efp7S.png)
I want to print the sum of sales and purchase price data separately based on its own date in the database

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/ Post the task, not only your attempt to solve it.

Comment: the task is written below "I want to print sum of sales and purchase price data seperately based on its own date in the database"

Comment: *the task is written below* I doubt. Such task definition means "I have obtained these values already into PHP code but I don't know how to print them on the screen". Whereas your explanations tells "I don't know how to calculate/obtain these values from MySQL tables". If I understand your problem correctly then read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and provide your structure/data according to "5. Some Additional Suggestions" and desired output for this data according to "3. Show Your Expected Outcome".

Comment: the task is to get the right sum values of sales.price and purchase.price based on the date of each database, the query written above can be executed, but the values not showing the right values. Please read the whole text, thank you

Comment: if using query of "SELECT SUM(price) AS price, date FROM sales GROUP BY date" the sum showing the right values, but when combined "SELECT SUM(price) AS price, date FROM sales, purchase GROUP BY date" the sum showing wrong values

Comment: *Please read the whole text* You have a problem in MySQL. But you post nothing about MySQL, you post PHP code instead. I won't read this because the provided code is not relative to the real problem.

Comment: Please read the whole problem, the problem is regarding the mysql output value is not correct. query is part of MYSQL

Comment: I have show the example result, hope it help